# illegal character with 10.0.2.2 when I call my webservice from android ADB

Tags: java, android, web-services, jakarta-ee, android-emulator

I made a webservice with netbeans (Java EE) and I want to communicate with my Android app (made with eclipse).

When I'm trying to communicate, for example, I call my webservice through my browser :

```
localhost:9999/SupRails_Start/resources/rest/mail@gmail.com/password
```

... And it give me a JSON, ...

With the ADB, I call that URI :

```
10.0.2.2:9999/SupRails_Start/resources/rest/mail@gmail.com/password
```

But it give me

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: 10.0.2.2:0000/SupRails_Start/resources/rest/...
```

When I copy-paste the JSON (received from the browser) into a php page and that I host it on the web, it's works perfectly !

Here is a part of my Android project :

```
WebService webService = new WebService("10.0.2.2:9999/SupRails_Start/resources/rest/wil.nad@gmail.com/root");
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String temp = webService.webGet("", params);
        Log.v("", "JSON received = "+temp);
```

Please help me I don't understand my mistake... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your web service URL is not complete. The syntax of a valid URL is like:

```
scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id
```

> Every URL consists of some of the following: the scheme name (commonly
>   called protocol), followed by a colon, two slashes,[note 1] then,
>   depending on scheme, a server name (exp. ftp., www., smtp., etc)
>   followed by a dot (.) then a domain name[note 2] (alternatively, IP
>   address), a port number, the path of the resource to be fetched or the
>   program to be run, then, for programs such as Common Gateway Interface
>   (CGI) scripts, a query string,[7][8] and an optional fragment
>   identifier.

[[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)

So change this:

```
new WebService("10.0.2.2:9999/SupRails_Start/resources/rest/wil.nad@gmail.com/root")
```

to this:

```
new WebService("http://10.0.2.2:9999/SupRails_Start/resources/rest/wil.nad@gmail.com/root")
```

Comment: @DaToop : thanks for your quick answer. I had already tried that one but it doesn't worked for me :-/

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: Concerning this exception this is the actual problem. Are you sure that after the change you actually compiled it and deployed it correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's running on my browser for the JEE and the android app works perfectly well with my php page that send a JSON.. All is working separately but not together :-/